# Defining a custom type as a subset of integers at the type level

Tags: types, ocaml

I'm interested in defining a primitive type (color channel) within the hierarchy of a larger image type. Since the type in question represents a bit, limiting its possible values to only those integers in the range 0 to 255 seems sensible. However, I'm not aware if implementing such constraints at the type level is something that's typically done in OCaml's type system.

`type channel = int (* restrict to range 0 -> 255 *)`

If doing so is legal within the OCaml type system, how should one go about defining constraints on the set of integers at the type level? **Put more concretely, how can a type be defined as a subset (range) of integers?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution is to define a module with a private type as follows:

```
module type INTERVAL = sig
  type t = private int
  val of_int : int -> t (* fails if value outside bounds *)
end

let interval a b = (module struct
  type t = int

  let of_int v =
    if v < a || v > b
    then failwith (Printf.sprintf "Not in interval [%d, %d]" a b)
    else v
end : INTERVAL)
```

Example of use:

```
let () =
  let module Small_int = (val (interval 0 255) : INTERVAL) in
  let x = Small_int.of_int (read_int ()) in
  print_int ((x :> int) * 2)
```

Modules built this way allow you to use a restricted set of integer values. However they have several drawbacks:

- You have to convert values back to integer before you can use operators on them (with the :> operator, as shown in the example);
- The type itself does not give you any information on the actual bounds allowed; you have to look into the implementation or to read the documentation in order to know what the type means;
- The memory space used is one integer, not one byte in this case;
- If you instanciate two modules with the same bounds, their types t will not be compatible.

Concerning the first drawback nothing restricts you from adding operations to the module type:

```
module type INTERVAL = sig
  type t = private int
  val of_int : int -> t
  val ( + ) : t -> t -> t
  val print_int : t -> unit
end

let interval a b = (module struct
  type t = int

  let of_int v =
    if v < a || v > b
    then failwith "Not in interval"
    else v

  let ( + ) x y = of_int (x + y)

  let print_int x = print_int x
end : INTERVAL)


let () =
  let module Small_int = (val (interval 0 255) : INTERVAL) in
  let x = Small_int.of_int (read_int ()) in
  let y = Small_int.of_int (read_int ()) in
  Small_int.(print_int (x + y));
  print_newline ()
```

The second drawback can be overcome with some conventions you declare in your project's documentation.

This is sometimes useful when you want to be sure that the input given to a function is in some "legal" range. If you are new to OCaml, I'm not sure you want to use this, but still it can be useful to know that it can be done.

Comment: nice solution. By this way, you can even enforce the arithmetic you wish to get : either + can trigger an exception, or performs some modular arith.

Answer (score 1):

If you define such subtypes, how would Ocaml derive the operations that apply to this subtypes ? (+,-,*,-). And the operations between initial type and its subtype ?

Except for objects in Ocaml, there is no way to define a constraint type by narrowing the definition of another type.

In your case, `channel` shall be mapped to `char` type - but it remains to define all the operations you need for implementing arithmetics.

Comment: mapping `channel` to `char` is a fantastic solution. It makes sense that types can't be constrained in the manner I suggested when the headache of maintaining such constraints in operations as simple as arithmetic. I didn't want to rule out the possibility without good reason though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a Functor :

```
module type Elt_type =
  sig
    type t
    val min       : t
    val max       : t
    val (<)       : t -> t -> bool
    val (>)       : t -> t -> bool
    val (+)       : t -> t -> t
    val print     : t -> unit
  end

module Make (Elt : Elt_type)  =
  struct
    type t'      = Set of Elt.t
    let of_t x   = 
      if Elt.(<) x Elt.min || Elt.(>) x Elt.max
          then failwith "Not in interval"
      else Set x
    let to_t x'  = let Set x=x' in x
    let (+) x' y'= of_t (Elt.(+) (to_t x') (to_t y'))
    let print x' = Elt.print (to_t x')
  end

module Int =Make (
  struct
    type t       = int
    let  min     = 1
    let  max     = 10
    let  (<)     = Pervasives.(<)
    let  (>)     = Pervasives.(>)
    let  (+)     = Pervasives.(+)
    let print    = Pervasives.print_int
  end)
```

Test :

```
# open Int
# let x = of_t 2;;
val x : Int.t' = Set 2
# let y = of_t 3;;
val y : Int.t' = Set 3
# print (x + y);;
5- : unit = ()
```